# Keycloak with Quarkus datasource configuration with validation attributes

Tags: postgresql, validation, jdbc, keycloak, quarkus

I'd like config jdbc with validation like this (on wildfly):

```
<validation>
     <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
     <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
     <background-validation-millis>10000</background-validation-millis>
</validation>
```

I can't config it on Keycloak. There is possible if I config a Quarkus datasource. But i'm afraid Keycloak can't use on quarkus configured datasorce...

Can I some way config validationQuery, and it's running attributes?
Can Keyclok work with Quarkus create datasource?
How can I config JDBC_PING and keycloak datasource simple and secure. (without plaintext password or ssl)

Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keycloak map KC prefixed properties to quarkus properties.
The class is :

*org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.configuration.mappers.DatabasePropertyMappers* on

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-quarkus-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

So keycloak's datasource should be quarkus datasource!

You can use these environment variables:

```
SET QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_JDBC_VALIDATION_QUERY_SQL=select 1
SET QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_JDBC_BACKGROUND_VALIDATION_INTERVAL=10
SET QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_JDBC_FOREGROUND_VALIDATION_INTERVAL=10
```

Other interesting thing, that JNDI doesn't supported by quarkus, so JDBC_PING cannot parameterized by *datasource_jndi_name*.

But you can use environment variables like this:

```
    <JDBC_PING
        connection_driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
        connection_username="${env.KC_DB_USERNAME}"
        connection_url="${env.KC_DB_URL}"
        initialize_sql="CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ${env.KC_DB_SCHEMA:public}; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${env.KC_DB_SCHEMA:public}.JGROUPSPING (own_addr varchar(200) NOT NULL, cluster_name varchar(200) NOT NULL, bind_addr varchar(200) NOT NULL, updated timestamp default current_timestamp, ping_data BYTEA, constraint PK_JGROUPSPING PRIMARY KEY (own_addr, cluster_name));"
        insert_single_sql="INSERT INTO ${env.KC_DB_SCHEMA:public}.JGROUPSPING (own_addr, cluster_name, bind_addr, updated, ping_data) values (?, ?, '${env.JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_EXTERNAL_IP:127.0.0.1}', NOW(), ?);"
        delete_single_sql="DELETE FROM ${env.KC_DB_SCHEMA:public}.JGROUPSPING WHERE own_addr=? AND cluster_name=?;"
        select_all_pingdata_sql="SELECT ping_data, own_addr, cluster_name FROM ${env.KC_DB_SCHEMA:public}.JGROUPSPING WHERE cluster_name=?"
        info_writer_sleep_time="500"
        remove_all_data_on_view_change="true"
        stack.combine="REPLACE"
        stack.position="MPING"
    />
```

SSL and other settings you could set as jdbc_url parameter.
Here is some description:
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/